# Ubuntu not booting (after fsck in GUI then probable power loss)

Tags: boot, luks, initramfs

I would appreciate any help with my problem.
At this point I would be happy if I can access my data on sda3 and reinstall OS.

My Ubuntu is not booting correctly after:

1. fsck run in GUI
2. fsck finished very quickly, I tried power off
3. unusual long time, I went to sleep
4. in the morning probably power cable was disconnected
5. Ubuntu not booting, hangs on "loading initial ramdisk..."

My sda3 was LUKS crypted partition.

Then:

1. recovery mode - the same ramdisk message
2. liveusb - many attemps with fsck, smartools, boot-repair
3. boot-repair was doing things but with no effects
4. sda3 was decrypted and now is LVM2
5. after #4 "default repair" button in boot-repair disappeared and never came back
6. can't mount /dev/sda3: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'
7. can mount /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root
8. couldn't chroot anywhere: failed to run command /bin/bash: no such file or directory
9. tried grub repairs: grub-install failed to get canonical path of /cow
10. many fsck attepts: Ubuntu is now booting straight to initramfs
11. fsck from initramfs level: 15 minutes of processing, no effect

boot-repair log:

```
    boot-repair-4ppa130                                              [20210911_1022]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 
    33264 of the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location 
    and looks for (,gpt1)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    
    fshelp fat part_gpt biosdisk
    

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /grub/grub.cfg

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       LVM2_member
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb: ___________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       iso9660
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: /mnt/BootInfo/FD/sdb: /dev/sdb already mounted or mount point busy.


================================ 0 OS detected =================================


============================ Architecture/Host Info ============================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, focal, x86_64)


===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS is EFI-compatible, and is setup in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled.

efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 2001,0000,2003,2002
Boot0000* Ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,d1b862c2-264d-4559-a451-f8aa6fe12037,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi)RC
Boot0001* EFI Network 0 for IPv4 (C4-54-44-2A-D1-2F)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x3)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(c454442ad12f,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)RC
Boot0002* EFI Network 0 for IPv6 (C4-54-44-2A-D1-2F)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x3)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(c454442ad12f,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0)RC
Boot0003* EFI USB Device (General USB Flash Disk)   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(3,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x2cf4ba3a,0x506fcc,0x1f40)RC
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC
This session has been detected as 'live' because df -Th / contains overlay

2895d47544fd587b26c7e29be1295c27   sda1/BOOT/fbx64.efi
621356d82b109cd860ad92cdf241c58b   sda1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
dc3c47be2f78a78e5e57d097ae6c5c84   sda1/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
   sda1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
78415fb8fb9b909f8029858113f1335f   sda1/BOOT/BOOTX64.efi


============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os, 2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda1    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda2    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  grubenv-ng, noupdategrub,   not-far

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda1    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda2    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  : maybesepboot, no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda1    : not-sepboot,  no-kernel,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda2    : is-sepboot,   no-kernel,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 111.81 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Disk identifier: 381A06AF-20CB-4240-A707-42486C122C06
        Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
sda1     2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
sda2  1050624   2549759   1499136   732M Linux filesystem
sda3  2549760 234440703 231890944 110.6G Linux filesystem
Disk sdb: 3.75 GiB, 4008706048 bytes, 7829504 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x2cf4ba3a
      Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
sdb1  *          0 5999871 5999872  2.9G  0 Empty
sdb2       5271500 5279499    8000  3.9M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
sdb3       6000640 7829503 1828864  893M 83 Linux
Disk mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 102.64 GiB, 110188560384 bytes, 215212032 sectors
Disk mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 7.94 GiB, 8506048512 bytes, 16613376 sectors

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:120GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:ATA Samsung SSD 840:;
1:1049kB:538MB:537MB:fat32:EFI System Partition:boot, esp;
2:538MB:1305MB:768MB:ext4::;
3:1305MB:120GB:119GB:::;
sdb:4009MB:scsi:512:512:unknown:General USB Flash Disk:;
mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1:8506MB:dm:512:512:unknown:Linux device-mapper (linear):;
mapper/ubuntu--vg-root:110GB:dm:512:512:loop:Linux device-mapper (linear):;
1:0.00B:110GB:110GB:ext4::;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME                  FSTYPE      UUID                                   PARTUUID                             LABEL                    PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                                                    
â”œâ”€sda1                vfat        CBCE-71F8                              d1b862c2-264d-4559-a451-f8aa6fe12037                          EFI System Partition
â”œâ”€sda2                ext4        ac591b5f-e430-4eff-be6b-805ce4e2f616   476d9ed9-fee6-4c4f-8692-2c486a2d298b                          
â””â”€sda3                LVM2_member xTmgzp-d21r-lpyI-1ySR-yyBI-d35I-B1JrG6 64273ae2-276f-4c57-b919-634773689620                          
  â”œâ”€ubuntu--vg-root   ext4        b68550fc-2f5f-470e-9eb6-41cbcbde0cfb                                                                 
  â””â”€ubuntu--vg-swap_1                                                                                                                  
sdb                   iso9660     2021-08-19-11-03-38-00                                                      Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS amd64 
â”œâ”€sdb1                iso9660     2021-08-19-11-03-38-00                 2cf4ba3a-01                          Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS amd64 
â”œâ”€sdb2                vfat        54C5-9C6C                              2cf4ba3a-02                                                   
â””â”€sdb3                ext4        44f79909-d06b-427a-9b75-46fac9ec2764   2cf4ba3a-03                          writable                 

df (filtered): _________________________________________________________________

                                                          Avail Use% Mounted on
disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2021-09-11.4/crash] 725.6M   9% /var/crash
disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2021-09-11.4/log]   725.6M   9% /var/log
mapper/ubuntu--vg-root                                      95G   0% /mnt/boot-sav/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root
sda1                                                     499.6M   2% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
sda2                                                     496.8M  22% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
sdb1                                                          0 100% /cdrom

Mount options: __________________________________________________________________

disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2021-09-11.4/crash] rw,relatime
disk/by-label/writable[/install-logs-2021-09-11.4/log]   rw,relatime
mapper/ubuntu--vg-root                                   rw,relatime
sda1                                                     rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
sda2                                                     rw,relatime
sdb1                                                     ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048

============================== ls -R /dev/mapper/ ==============================

/dev/mapper:
control
ubuntu--vg-root
ubuntu--vg-swap_1

===================== sda1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

search.fs_uuid ac591b5f-e430-4eff-be6b-805ce4e2f616 root hd0,gpt2 
set prefix=($root)'/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

==================== sda1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img                     1

======================== sda2/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) =========================

Ubuntu   b68550fc-2f5f-470e-9eb6-41cbcbde0cfb
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-154-generic   b68550fc-2f5f-470e-9eb6-41cbcbde0cfb
Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-153-generic   b68550fc-2f5f-470e-9eb6-41cbcbde0cfb
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
System setup   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

==================== sda2: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
   0.729499817 = 0.783294464    grub/grub.cfg                                  3
   0.641658783 = 0.688975872    vmlinuz-4.15.0-153-generic                     1
   0.688533783 = 0.739307520    vmlinuz-4.15.0-154-generic                     2
   0.836910248 = 0.898625536    initrd.img-4.15.0-153-generic                  9
   0.903171539 = 0.969773056    initrd.img-4.15.0-154-generic                 50


======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc =========================

Unknown BootLoader on sdb

00000000  45 52 08 00 00 00 90 90  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |ER..............|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000020  33 ed fa 8e d5 bc 00 7c  fb fc 66 31 db 66 31 c9  |3......|..f1.f1.|
00000030  66 53 66 51 06 57 8e dd  8e c5 52 be 00 7c bf 00  |fSfQ.W....R..|..|
00000040  06 b9 00 01 f3 a5 ea 4b  06 00 00 52 b4 41 bb aa  |.......K...R.A..|
00000050  55 31 c9 30 f6 f9 cd 13  72 16 81 fb 55 aa 75 10  |U1.0....r...U.u.|
00000060  83 e1 01 74 0b 66 c7 06  f3 06 b4 42 eb 15 eb 02  |...t.f.....B....|
00000070  31 c9 5a 51 b4 08 cd 13  5b 0f b6 c6 40 50 83 e1  |1.ZQ....[...@P..|
00000080  3f 51 f7 e1 53 52 50 bb  00 7c b9 04 00 66 a1 b0  |?Q..SRP..|...f..|
00000090  07 e8 44 00 0f 82 80 00  66 40 80 c7 02 e2 f2 66  |..D.....f@.....f|
000000a0  81 3e 40 7c fb c0 78 70  75 09 fa bc ec 7b ea 44  |.>@|..xpu....{.D|
000000b0  7c 00 00 e8 83 00 69 73  6f 6c 69 6e 75 78 2e 62  ||.....isolinux.b|
000000c0  69 6e 20 6d 69 73 73 69  6e 67 20 6f 72 20 63 6f  |in missing or co|
000000d0  72 72 75 70 74 2e 0d 0a  66 60 66 31 d2 66 03 06  |rrupt...f`f1.f..|
000000e0  f8 7b 66 13 16 fc 7b 66  52 66 50 06 53 6a 01 6a  |.{f...{fRfP.Sj.j|
000000f0  10 89 e6 66 f7 36 e8 7b  c0 e4 06 88 e1 88 c5 92  |...f.6.{........|
00000100  f6 36 ee 7b 88 c6 08 e1  41 b8 01 02 8a 16 f2 7b  |.6.{....A......{|
00000110  cd 13 8d 64 10 66 61 c3  e8 1e 00 4f 70 65 72 61  |...d.fa....Opera|
00000120  74 69 6e 67 20 73 79 73  74 65 6d 20 6c 6f 61 64  |ting system load|
00000130  20 65 72 72 6f 72 2e 0d  0a 5e ac b4 0e 8a 3e 62  | error...^....>b|
00000140  04 b3 07 cd 10 3c 0a 75  f1 cd 18 f4 eb fd 00 00  |.....<.u........|
00000150  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001b0  94 5a 4f 00 00 00 00 00  3a ba f4 2c 00 00 80 00  |.ZO.....:..,....|
000001c0  01 00 00 b7 e0 fa 00 00  00 00 00 8d 5b 00 00 fe  |............[...|
000001d0  ff ff ef fe ff ff cc 6f  50 00 40 1f 00 00 00 85  |.......oP.@.....|
000001e0  51 75 83 5c 75 e7 00 90  5b 00 00 e8 1b 00 00 00  |Qu.\u...[.......|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200


=============================== StdErr Messages ================================

File descriptor 63 (pipe:[74824]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 7122: /bin/bash
File descriptor 63 (pipe:[74824]) leaked on lvchange invocation. Parent PID 17388: /bin/bash
/usr/share/boot-sav/b-i-s-functions.sh: line 1653: 215212032S: value too great for base (error token is "215212032S")

================================= User choice ==================================

Is there RAID on this computer? no

================================ LVM activation ================================

modprobe dm-mod  
vgscan --mknodes
  Found volume group "ubuntu-vg" using metadata type lvm2
vgchange -ay
  2 logical volume(s) in volume group "ubuntu-vg" now active
lvscan
  ACTIVE            '/dev/ubuntu-vg/root' [102.62 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/ubuntu-vg/swap_1' [7.92 GiB] inherit
blkid -g

Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would not act on the boot.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As I mentioned - any way that will allow me to backup the data will be enough.

Comment: You haven't said what release of Ubuntu you're trying to repair, but grub 2.00 implies it's from late-2012 or early-2013 and only supported releases of Ubuntu are on-topic here. Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site.

Comment: @guiverc taken from boot-repair log my Ubuntu is: CPU architecture: 64-bit
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, focal, x86_64).

Comment: I was asking about the installed system, not the *live* system (grub 2.04 is the version used by 20.04)

Comment: Can I check the version from the liveusb terminal level?

Comment: The file `/etc/os-release` should contain that detail; however that will show your *live* system as well; so adjust for your `mounted` installed system (and encryption if it's sda3)

Comment: from initramfs level (without liveusb): VERSION=18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver). And from the boot menu level during the boot: 4.15.0-154-generic is available as a choice.